# To cancel the error display if there is no picture value in the database

Tags: codeigniter

Actually I am working on front-end, but I cannot reach the backend developer and I need to fix a bug.

The problem is exactly this, if there is no image in a content, we get an error like this:

> A PHP Error was encountered
> A
> Severity: Notice
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass:$Pictures
> Filename:agent/hotel_detail.php
> Line Number: 17
> Backtrace:
> File:/home/tungatour/public_html/application/views/agent/hotel_detail.php
> Line: 17
> Function: _error_handler
> File:/home/tungatour/public_html/application/controllers/Agent.php
> Line: 490
> Function: view
> File:/home/tungatour/public_htm/index.php

I just want to show demo image instead if there is no image. But i  dont have any idea how can i do this ?

so i have controller codes about picture this this.

```
public function post($ID)
{
    $viewData["title"] = "Post Details";
    $data = $this->db->where("ID", $ID)->get("post")->row();
    $data->Meta = json_decode($data->Meta);
    $picture = $this->db->where("ID", $data->Meta->Thumbnail)->get("picture")->row();
    $viewData["data"] = $data;
    $viewData["picture"] = $picture;

    $this->load->view('partials/agent/head', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('agent/post', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('partials/agent/foot', $viewData);
}
```

also i have this lines`  <?php $first = true;

```
                            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->db->where_in("ID", $data->Meta->Pictures)->count_all_results("picture"); $i++) { ?>

                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?= $i ?>" class="<?= $first ? "active" : "" ?>"></li>

                            <?php $first = false;

                            } ?>

                        </ol>

                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                            <?php $first = true;

                            foreach ($this->db->where_in("ID", $data->Meta->Pictures)->get("picture")->result() as $picture) { ?>

                                <div class="carousel-item <?= $first ? "active" : "" ?>">

                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="<?= $picture->URL ?>" style="height: 420px;width: 100%;object-fit: cover;" />

                                </div>

                            <?php $first = false;

                            } ?>

                        </div>`
```

Comment: why not make a check: if picture exists show it, if not show demo image ?

Answer (score 0):

**Change this line**

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="<?= $picture->URL ?>" style="height: 420px;width: 100%;object-fit: cover;" />
```

**Update with**

```
<?php if($picture->URL) { ?>
<img class="img-fluid" src="<?= $picture->URL ?>" style="height: 420px;width: 100%;object-fit: cover;" />
<?php } ?>
```

If the image has a URL, it will display the image. Otherwise it will be empty.

Comment: Teşekkür ederim ancak çalıştıramadım. Dbde resim olmadığı için hatalı çekiyor. Aslında yapmak istediğim şey controller ile yapılabilir gibi geliyor. Eğer resim yoksa demo resim olarak şunu göster gibi. Ama dediğim gibi back end olayına çok hakim değilim. :)

Comment: Bu satırı
foreach ($this->db->where_in("ID", $data->Meta->Pictures)->get("picture")->result() as $picture) { ?>
Şu şekilde değiştirip dener misiniz:
foreach ($picture as $picture) { ?>
veya
hotel_detail view dosyanızdaki 17. satırı yazar mısınız orada hata gözüküyor.